# Updating ASP.NET Core Web Application packages causes build errors

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-core

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with all extensions updated. I have an empty solution and create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)". I choose to create a "Web Application" with no authentication. The project is created and it runs fine.

I open nuget package manager and it says there are 15 updates. Many look like the are updating to version 1.1. I choose to install all these updates. On rebuilding my project I get the following build warnings

> Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
> 2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
> 3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding

```
{
    ...

    "runtimes": {
        "win10-x64": {}
    },

    ...
}
```

to my `project.json` fixed the issue (I'm running windows 10).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: Hi Wendy. I've got to wait another 13 hours to accepts my answer

Comment: @KevinBrydon you wouldn't need to add that runtimes config section if you installed the Core 1.1 SDK on your dev environment.